# cookies for different users

Tags: security, authentication, cookies

we have a web application and we use a persistent cookie to store some user preferences. it works fine with single user. however, when user uses a different user name to login, it will overwrite the previous cookie.

somehow product guy wants it support multiple users, meaning each user has their own cookie.

One of my teammates suggests that it can name the cookie like "mycookiename" + encodedUserId to create different cookie for each different user.

it might work. but my gut feeling seems tell me that it would pose some security concern as potentially one's cookie is totally visible to other users.

any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why are overlapping cookies a problem, do multiple users use the same browser? (The vastly more sane approach would be storing preferences on server side, though, where they belong, for security reasons as much as convenience - what happens if a user changes browsers/computers?)

Comment: I would use Local Storage instead of cookies, it's better in the way you don't need to send preferences of all users every request. To secure preferences, you can encode it using your own algorithm based on user id, which is also send with encoded preferences.